# PowerShell - Clone a HashSet (deep copy)

Tags: powershell

How can I create a clone of a HashSet in PowerShell? I can easily assign one HashSet = to another, but then if I change one it will affect the other by reference. Is there a method to create a clone (deep copy), or do I have to do it manually in a loop? I was hoping I could just use `.Clone()` but I guess that method doesn't exist on HashSets.

Minor detail: I don't care about cloning the exact hashes, only the values.

Comment: That really depends on the objects you're adding to the hashset, are those objects of a reference type or not? If not you can simply create a new hash using the original hashset as the ctor argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To obtain a copy of an existing hashset, simply create a new one and pass the existing one as a constructor argument, along with its comparer:

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic

# Create initial hashset
$initialSet = [HashSet[int]]::new([int[]]@(1..100))

# Create a snapshot of it
$copiedSet = [HashSet[int]]::new($initialSet, $initialSet.Comparer)
```

You'll notice they're distinct - you can manipulate one without affecting the other:

```
PS ~> $copiedSet.RemoveWhere({$args[0] % 2}) # remove all odd numbers |Out-Null
PS ~> $copiedSet.Count
50
PS ~> $initialSet.Count # initial set unaffected
100
```

The [target constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-hashset-1-ctor(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-0)))) takes an `[IEnumerable[T]]` as its argument - and since `[HashSet[T]]` implements `[IEnumerable[T]]`, PowerShell will pass it along without attempting any type coercion - making it work faster than had you unrolled the initial set and added each member to the new set manually.

This pattern can be turned into a small helper function:

```
function Copy-HashSet {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    $Original
  )

  $targetType = $Original.GetType()

  if(-not($targetType.IsGenericType -and $targetType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Name -eq 'HashSet`1')){
    throw 'Wrong type, expected [HashSet[T]]'
  }
  else {
    # use the static member operator (::) to resolve the constructor - no need to discover the parameter type manually!
    return $Original::new($Original, $Original.Comparer)
  }
}
```

---

Beware that this is technically a *shallow copy* - if you populate the initial hash set with reference type objects then the identical members of both sets will still point to the same objects:

```
$myObject = [pscustomobject]@{Value=123}

$set1 = [HashSet[psobject]]::new()
$set1.Add($myObject) |Out-Null

$set2 = [HashSet[psobject]]::new($set1, $set1.Comparer)
```

```
PS ~> $copyObject = $set2 |Select-Object -First 1
PS ~> $copyObject.Value = 987
PS ~> $myObject  # turns out it wasn't actually a copy...

Value
-----
  987
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias! That makes sense that if the HS has reference type objects then each of those would need to be clone manually for a true deep copy, but in my case and most cases it's just a primitive data type. The only thing I had to change was `using namespace` instead of just `using`.